# Rails query with group and count must include zeros

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I know this question has been asked before but I have read many of the posts and tried applying them to my situation and I just can't get it working.  I'm a beginner who could use some help.  Here are my models:

```
class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Student
  belongs_to :Meeting
  belongs_to :ClassSection
end

class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :floorplan
  has_many :actions
  belongs_to :class_section

end
```

I am trying to get a count of actions for a single student across multiple meetings, including meetings where he/she had 0 actions.  So, if there are two rows in the meetings table, ID=1 and ID=2, and student 83 has a single action with meeting_id=1 in the actions table, my query, which will include *where(:student_id=>83)* somewhere, should return something like

1=>1

2=>0

I hope this makes sense.  I know the answer involves outer joins but I am bad at implementing them in pure SQL and worse at doing them through ActiveRecord. FYI I am using MYSQL. Thanks in advance for whatever help you can provide.

Comment: unrelated to your question, but typical style would have the `belongs_to` associations all downcase: `belongs_to :student`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Meeting
  .joins('LEFT JOIN actions ON meeting_id = meetings.id')
  .where(student_id: 83)
  .group('meetings.id')
  .count('actions.id')
```

**Explanation**

- **`.joins`** is the left/outer join that you intuited that you needed. It means "include at least one row for every meeting, even if there are no actions".
- **`.group`** needs to be on the meeting id, since this will always be present and different meetings should be grouped separately.
- **`.count`** needs to be on actions id. `COUNT` *does not* count null records, so meetings with no actions will be counted as 0.

It's a little bit weird that for a count of *actions* you nee to start your query with `Meeting`, but that is necessary when you want to include 0 counts. Otherwise there would be no way for SQL to know what meetings were missing!

For reference, the generated SQL is:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(actions.id) AS count_actions_id,
  meetings.id AS meetings_id
FROM "meetings" LEFT JOIN actions ON meeting_id = meetings.id
GROUP BY meetings.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work fine just by grouping

```
Meeting.where(student_id: 83).group(:actions).count
```

This will return the hash you want

```
{1=>1, 2=>0}
```

Comment: what version of ARel? This doesn't work for me - the generated SQL is invalid.

Comment: what error did you get?, could you paste me the query with `to_sql`